# Problems Installing Metasploit Framework on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ruby, gem, metasploit, ruby-on-rails

I have encountered 3 problems while following [this](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/) guide to installing Metasploit Framework on Ubuntu and Debian:

1) After installing proper version of ruby, there is a command given for installing Ruby libraries: `sudo gem install bundler`. When I typed that in and hit enter, it says `command not found`. After some researching on the internet, I decided to remove `sudo` and try again. So I've entered `gem install bundler` and it worked fine. Will this cause any problems?

2) After installing Metasploit Framework, there is a command given to install the required gems and versions:

```
cd metasploit-framework
bundle install
```

But when I tried that, I got this error:

```
rbenv: version '2.1.6' is not installed
```

I really don't know what to do next (But I moved on).

3) Probably due to the previous problems, in the end when I executed msfconsole command, it said

```
could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources.
```

run bundle install to install the missing gems
But the bundle install doesn't help either, because when I run that it says

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** When I asked the person himself who had written the guide, regarding this, he told me to select the version of ruby I had just installed with either rebind or RVM before installing bundler, and then  to run the bundle install. Could you please list the commands to do so? I am really new to Linux!

Comment: I guess you used rbind? If you did, `rbenv install 2.1.6` and 
`rbenv global 2.1.6` followed by `gem install bundler` may work. Also which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: Hi! I have edited the post and have added the link to my guide ( click 'this'). I had used rbind, and yes i had done the installation of that gem previously as it was stated in the guide. But i did it again, and the problem remains.

Comment: I had issues with the installation too.  Have you tried `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`? Just a thought.